# Is there any relation between the grassmannian set and the quotient group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, quotient-group

I was searching on google about quotient groups and quotient topology when I read a statement

> The quotient group $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$/$P$ (by the right action of $P$) is the same as the Grassmannian set.

I want to know if there is any isomorphism or homomorphism between the set $Gr_k(V)$ and the quotient group $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$/$P$ by the right action of $P$, where $P$ is the subspace $Span$($e_1$,.....,$e_k$) (which is basically an isotropy subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. I am having difficulty knowing why are they both the same? I am familiar with the elements of both spaces but I don't see how are they equal? If there is any simple explanation that could clear up my misunderstanding I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you spell out this part '$P$ is basically an isotropy subgroup'?

Comment: @Berci I meant $P$ is a isotropy subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ at some convenient point of the Grassmannian space. It depends on the point that will give the isotropy group to be the subspace spanned by ($e_1$,....,$e_k$). Is that clear enough ?